# Why are my Docker images 2 weeks out of date?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-for-windows

The current time & the time on my windows PC is 12:24 on 4/6/21, but running

```
docker exec -it {container} date
```

Gives me the time Fri May 21 06:43:19 UTC 2021, which is a little over 2 weeks behind. From what I've read, docker should be taking the date from my machine, so I can't figure out why they're so out of sync.

Stopping & upping my docker-compose doesnt reset the time - the gap remains the same.
What do I need to do to get them synced? Is there something missing from my docker-compose file?

Comment: Did you build the image or pulled and ran?

Comment: What's your host OS?

Comment: ...it's Windows, I see.  Does restarting Docker Desktop help, or using one of the more aggressive "reset" options?

Comment: Hope that duplicate solves your question. If not, update your question to show how it's different and tag me in a comment so I can reopen.

Comment: @BMitch I solved this by restarting Docker Desktop, but yes that duplicate helped. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Docker takes date/time based on its own time/zone settings, as explained at https://www.ivankrizsan.se/2015/10/31/time-in-docker-containers/ .

Try to synchronize it by adding to your image the NTPd service as demostrated in above article.

Comment: The time zone is based on `/etc/localtime` inside the container, but the actual clock itself is shared with the host (and maintained by the host's kernel) (on native Linux).  It'd be very unusual to run ntpd inside a container; both because it would change the host-global time, and because a container usually only runs one process.

Comment: @DavidMaze In that case, what would you suggest? It's not just a timezone problem anyway - the date is way off too